# Design of HA, consistent and responsive counter

Tags: scalability, high-availability, system-design

Lets say flipkart launched a exclusive redmi sale by 12PM, stock is 10K but more people will access at same time. There are adv and disadv of keeping the counter in single machine or distributed. If we keep it in some in-memory data store single machine, the machine will become bottleneck as many app machines will retrieve at same time, have to consider memory and cpu for queueing those requests. If its distributed across nodes and machines access different nodes, here we eliminate bottleneck, but a update in node has to be consistent across nodes, this will also affect response time. What can be the design choice for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a single machine counter will be really a performance bottleneck during intensive load and a single point of failure as well. I would suggest to go for a [sharded counter](http://highscalability.com/numbers-everyone-should-know) implementation.